# printf in shell script can't do \x%x

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing, printf, hex

where `ECHO-VAR` produces `\xFF\xFF\xFF\x00` (`$fb_COLOR15`) these work on the command line:

```
CP="`ECHO-VAR`" printf $CP | dd status=none bs=4 count=$(( ( 1360 * 100 ) + 100 )) > /dev/fb0
printf "`ECHO-VAR`" | dd status=none bs=4 count=$(( ( 1360 * 100 ) + 100 )) > /dev/fb0
printf "${fb_COLOR15}" | dd status=none bs=4 count=$(( ( 1360 * 100 ) + 100 )) > /dev/fb0
```

but they don't work in a shell script (`#!/bin/sh`). It will only output `\xFF\xFF\xFF\x00` or `xFFxFFxFFx00` instead of four (4) characters, even if piped through `sed 's/\\/\\\\\\\\\\/g'`.

these work but with `bash: printf: missing hex digit for \x` (x4), they produce what you expect at the end:

```
printf `printf "\x%x\x%x\x%x\x%x" 255 255 255 0` | dd status=none bs=4 count=$(( ( 1360 * 100 ) + 100 )) > /dev/fb0
printf "`printf "\\x%x\\x%x\\x%x\\x%x" 255 255 255 0`" | dd status=none bs=4 count=$(( ( 1360 * 100 ) + 100 )) > /dev/fb0
printf "`printf "\\\x%x\\\x%x\\\x%x\\\x%x" 255 255 255 0`" | dd status=none bs=4 count=$(( ( 1360 * 100 ) + 100 )) > /dev/fb0
printf "`printf "\\\\x%x\\\\x%x\\\\x%x\\\\x%x" 255 255 255 0`" | dd status=none bs=4 count=$(( ( 1360 * 100 ) + 100 )) > /dev/fb0
```

however this works (five slashes):

```
printf "`printf "\\\\\x%x\\\\\x%x\\\\\x%x\\\\\x%x" 255 255 255 0`" | dd status=none bs=4 count=$(( ( 1360 * 100 ) + 100 )) > /dev/fb0
```

but not in a shell script (`#!/bin/sh`), it produces the same error.

I tried various combinations of ` execution, layered echo's and printf's for 5 hours before changing the input format from \x type to the four decimal argument format, which still failed.

---

FYI: they will produce a white dot on a 32bit framebuffer.

In 5 minutes I got it to work from both the command line and in a shell script using:

```
bas d2a.bas 255 255 255 0 | dd status=none bs=4 count=$(( ( 1360 * 100 ) + 100 )) > /dev/fb0
```

`d2a.bas`:

```
 1 rem D2A.BAS - decimal arguments to ASCII characters
 10 for i=1 to 255
 20   a$=command$(i)
 30   if a$="" then
 40     i=255
 50   else
 60     a=val(A$)
 70     print chr$(a);
 80   end if
 90 next
```

---

I understand that the shell process one layer of escaped \ characters for each level of abstraction, and that a command or binary (I also tested `/usr/bin/printf`) parses another layer of escaped \ characters.

But I don't understand why I could not get any form of either format to work in a shell script, which should work simply by adding an extra \ character for every one present in an output string.

Does anyone know what is going on, or is this an actual bug?

I believe this is a bug in BASH when in SH mode; see post below, or just save yourself the hassle and use the BAS script.

Answer (score 3):

`\` is used several times in there:

- for the `` `...` `` form of command substitution. Best is to use `$(...)`.
- to escape characters like `$`, `` ` `` and `\` inside double quotes. Best to use single quotes instead.
- to escape `\` in the format argument of `printf`
- to introduce that `\xHH` sequence in the format argument of the other `printf` (not standard though).

So it should either be:

```
printf `printf "\\\\\\\\x%x" 255 255 255 0`
printf `printf '\\\\x%x' 255 255 255 0`
printf $(printf '\\x%x' 255 255 255 0)
```

That is, you need to pass `\\` to the rightmost `printf` for it to output `\`, but with `` `...` ``, you'd need  to escape each `\` with `\`, and do that again for `"..."`.

That's still invoking the split+glob operator which we don't want here. So:

```
printf "$(printf '\\x%x' 255 255 255 0)"
```

Or portably:

```
printf "$(printf '\\%o' 255 255 255 0)"
```

With some `awk` implementations (not all with work with 0):

```
LC_ALL=C awk 'BEGIN{printf "%c%c%c%c", 255, 255, 255, 0}'
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -e 'print pack "C*", @ARGV' 255 255 255 0
```

`zsh` alternative that avoids forking a subshell:

```
(){setopt localoptions nomultibyte; printf %s ${(#)@}} 255 255 255 0
```

`bash` alternative that  avoids forking a subshell (also works in recent versions of `zsh`):

```
printf -v x '\\%o' 255 255 255 0
printf "$x"
```

Comment: I just tested the "portably" (double printf) which worked. So basically I just missed the right combinations (specifically $( \\ and %o )

Comment: I want to keep maximum protability with low overhead, least installed, ie. not AWK and not PERL

Comment: with the \x form, when it should have worked in a script it was getting interfered with producing `xFFxFFxFFx00`

Comment: I really like the explanation of this answer, even after 5 years. IIRC this resulted in me using $(command) more and more over `command`, to the point that I only use `command` on forums now :)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem again, and this time I could not refactor the input data to make it `decimal`.

Unless anyone else can show otherwise, the internal `printf` in BASH when in SH mode *can* *not* print "\xFF" characters, despite what the man and help pages say. I would say this is a bug, in BASH at least.

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "\x46\x47"
```

If you remove the quotes from the string, the shell will escape them away without processing the `x` part.

What does work then:

```
#!/bin/sh
PF=`which printf`
$PF "\x46\x47"
```

So the current solution, if you only have *hexadecimal* *as* *text*, and you want a *character* or *byte*, pipe each (text) byte out to a script file (as the second code demonstrates) with `\x` prepended (before) each value, `chmod` the script from inside you script, then execute the script on the next line, and remove the script if need be.

Comment: upon reading this answer 5 years on, the last part of it does not clarify that _as the second code demonstrates_ is actually an _temp output script_ produced from within a _parent script_.